# Adapting Google Sheets API Node.js Quickstart to work with my own sheet, error: Error: Unable to parse range: Class Data!A2:E

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

[Sheets API Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/nodejs)

I'm working on a web application that basically takes a bunch of user-submitted data from a google form that's been stored in a google sheet, pulls the data from the google sheet, and I eventually want to take that data and store it in an SQL database file so we can use the data in our program from there.

So I ran through the quickstart in the link above, it worked, awesome. I then changed their spreadsheet id to the one my google sheet has that I'm trying to pull data from:

```
var sheets = google.sheets('v4');
sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  auth: auth,
  spreadsheetId: '1EV8S8AaAmxF3vP0F6RWxKIUlvF6uFEmsrOFWA1oNBYI',
  range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
},
```

Is there anything else I need to change in the quickstart code so that it will display my sheet's information? This is the link to my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EV8S8AaAmxF3vP0F6RWxKIUlvF6uFEmsrOFWA1oNBYI/edit?usp=sharing

and the string after the /d/ is my sheet's id.

Right now, trying to run the quickstart code with my sheet's id just produces the error: The API returned an error:

> Error: Unable to parse range: Class Data!A2:E

Comment: research and at least try the options. let us know of specific issues you run into. there is plenty of documentation and tutorials for both cases.

Comment: Thank you. I actually made a bit of progress trying to use the sheets node.js quickstart api. I'm updating this post at the moment.

Comment: Alright, so I changed the post to better reflect my current problem.

Comment: you said you changed the id from the sample. did you also change the range definition? (sheet named "Class Data" with data in range "A2:E"

Comment: Does it work if you put single quotes around 'Class Data', e.g, `'Class Data'!A1:E`

Comment: No I figured it out actually, you need to replace Class Data with the name of your sheet that you're using.. mine happened to be Form Responses 1 so when I changed it to that it worked.

Comment: thanks. i think you could remove `Class Data` too. i don't need it in my script. @Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you need to replace Class Data with the name of your sheet that you're using.. mine happened to be Form Responses 1 so when I changed it to that it worked

Answer (score 1):

**IF** there is only one Worksheet in the Google Spreadsheet **THEN**
when defining your range, you can omit the *Google Worksheet Name*

In your example:

`range: 'Class Data!A2:E',`

The *Google Worksheet Name* is '**Class Data**'.

You can find the *Google Worksheet Name* in the Tabs at the bottom of your Google Spreadsheet.

The default *Google Worksheet Name* is '***Sheet1***'.